# Passing content to a URL (Who.is)

Tags: html

I am going to need to add a form to a page on a site, that takes a domain name as the input from the viewer and sends it to who.is so that the DNS for this domains a returned.

When searching onwho.is, the URL for the search query when looking for me.com looks like this:

http://who.is/dns/me.com

I am struggling here since I can't pass the domain name using the variable form, with ?q=...

Any Ideas?

This is so far the html I have for this form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://who.is/dns/" target="_blank"> 
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" placeholder="Who is" width="255"/>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this in HTML unless you find a URL with parameters, like TechnoKnol posted.

You need this or a server process

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("who").onsubmit=function() {
    window.open("http://who.is/dns/"+document.getElementById("q").value(),"_blank");
    return false;
  }
}
```

using

```
<form id="who"> 
<input type="text" id="q" size="31" maxlength="255" placeholder="Who is" width="255"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting on [who.is](http://who.is), I found below url

```
http://who.is/search.php?search_type=Whois&query=me.com&commit=Search
```

With some modification in your form will work.